# ReactJS Styled-Components Causing Null Error When Rendering

Tags: css, reactjs, react-hooks, styled-components

I'm working on a simple React/Express website and I'm trying to implement CSS-in-JS using the styled-components library. My app rendered everything fine with normal .css files, but when I try to introduce a styled-component, nothing on the page renders and I get a bunch of errors in the console. In particular, I get a "`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useDebugValue')`" error.

My App.js file looks like this:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

import styled from 'styled-components'

import MainPage from './components/mainPage.component.js';

const AppWrapper = styled.div`
  text-align: center;
`;

class App extends Component {

  render() {

    return (
      <div>

          <AppWrapper>
          
            <NavBar />

            <Routes>
              <Route path="/" element={<MainPage />}/>
            </Routes>

          </AppWrapper>

      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

I tried messing around with the component, but I get the error no matter what file the styled-component is in and even if the component itself (like `\<AppWrapper\>`) doesn't contain anything. I also have received a "`Warning: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.`" error, but I'm not sure how this is related.

Any idea why this might be happening? Thanks!

Comment: Try commenting MainPage route and just try rendering a div in route element like this <Route path="/" element=<div/>>. If the error disappears there is something with the MainPage component.

Comment: @avanikothari The error happens even if AppWrapper is the only tag in my app, any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

For anyone else who encounters this problem, I think I found the solution. It happened with emotion (another css-in-js library) as well, so the issue wasn't with the particular library but rather with a library duplication in my dependencies. This thread explains it well: https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components/issues/3045 . I fixed the issue by uninstalling styled-components (which was installed in the root folder of my project) and re-installing it within my react/client-side folder.